# Django variable: declare in urls

Tags: django, django-urls

In urls.py:

```
(r'^bbb/id(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template,
    {'template': 'some.html', 'extra_context': {'user_id': user_id}}),
```

In some.html: `{{ user_id }}`

But there is an error: `name 'user_id' is not defined (in urls.py)`

So, how to declare that variable in urls.py and send it directly to 'some.html'???

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to put it in `extra_context`. It's already captured in the URL, so is present in the `params` dictionary in the template: `{{ params.user_id }}`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) - and also note that these old function-based generic views are deprecated, and you should be using the class-based [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#templateview).

Answer (score 0):

The variable really isn't declared in that python code. :) You do not need to set this variable in the view context. The view will receive named matches as **kwargs.

Comment: But as you see I use generic views... How send it directly to template?